# Connection refused error while deploying app on heroku server

Tags: python-2.7, pymongo, bottle, heroku-toolbelt

I am trying to deploy python application with bottle on heroku. I am using pymongo to connect to mongoDB. Once I start heroku server, it crashes with error "pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure: could not connect to localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused" .

I tried all basic troubleshooting such as removing the lock file and restarting mongod server. Still the issue persists. Here is the piece of code where I am making Mongod connection :

```
import pymongo
import os
import bottle
connection=pymongo.Connection(os.environ.get('MONGOLAB_URI', 'mongodb://localhost:27017'))
database = connection.Lab1282
```

NOTE: I have MONGOLAB add on has been added onto heroku server. Also this whole setup is running in amazon EC2 instance

Answer (score 0):

the `.get()` function tries to get the value from the first parameter, if it is not available or None then it'd use the second parameter

since it is using the `..localhost:27017` while you are on heroku, this means that the environment variable `MONGOLAB_URI` is not available, you need to make sure it is correctly set